# Saving a reference to an immediately invoked function

Tags: javascript

It seems that you're unable to set immediately invoked function expression to a variable:

```
var foo = function() {
  alert();
}(); // Immediately alerts 

foo(); // Returns "Uncaught TypeError: foo is not a function"
```

`foo` turns out to be undefined - but why? And is there any way to actually save a reference to an immediately invoked function?

Comment: Without an explicit return statement, `undefined` is returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It seems that you're unable to set immediately invoked function expression to a variable

That is incorrect

> `foo` turns out to be undefined - but why?

the code you've provided assigns the *return value* of the IIFE to `foo`.

If you had:

```
var foo = function() {
  alert();
  return 5;
}();
```

`foo` would have a value of `5`.

> And is there any way to actually save a reference to an immediately invoked function?

Yes, but it's not a good way to organize code:

```
var foo;
(foo = function () {
  alert('works just fine');
})();
```

Why do you need to immediately invoke the expression when you might as well declare a function:

```
function foo() {
  alert();
}
```

and then call the function:

```
foo();
```

Comment: What actually 
`(foo = function () {
  alert('works just fine');
})();`

would do? Will it execute `foo()` or `function()`?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the method suggested by zzzzBov, you can also do what you want using a named function expression and returning a reference from the function:

```js
var foo = (function foo() {
  alert();
  return foo; // Return a reference to this function
}()); // Immediately alerts 

foo();
```

However, as noted, it doesn't seem like a good idea. Just declare the function.

Also, it's considered good form to wrap IIFEs in parenthesis, even if not required, so that it's obvious from the start that it's an IIFE. Otherwise, it's not clear until you get to the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You have given () after the function which invokes the function and value of that function is assigned to the variable foo. So when you tries to call it on next it says uncaught type function. Just remove brackets.

```
var foo = function() {
   alert();
};
```

Comment: But then it's not an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) any more. ;-)